# Swift create enum in struct

Tags: swift

I want to create enum in my struct. I tried:

```
struct ProfileTextfieldItem {

    var txtfPlaceholder: String
    var bottomTxt: String
    var modelType : Int

    enum modelType {
        case phone
        case skype
    }
}
```

Then i did:

```
let tesEnum = ProfileTextfieldItem(txtfPlaceholder: "o.ivanova", bottomTxt: "Логин Skype", enumType: phone)
```

However compiler didn't let me run, it says - Use of unresolved identifier - phone.

Comment: Your initializer doesn't match the declaration anyway. The code doesn't compile. And `enum` types are supposed to start with a capital letter (`ModelType`). That avoids the confusion of the  type `modelType` vs. the variable name `modelType`.

Comment: @vadian thank you but i would like to see your representation of that task if possible.

Comment: My representation is equal to paper1111's.

Comment: @vadian i wonder who downvote him, i supposed you may did (as wrong answer)

Comment: I did not. The answer is correct

Comment: @vadian when i try to add modelType to protocol it throw me an error: use of undeclared type 'ModelType'. I declare protocol like that - protocol ProfileTextEditTapProtocol : class {
    func didTapModelWIthTypeAndNewText(type: ModelType, text: String)
}

Comment: As the enum is declared within a struct it's a *subtype* of the struct and  you have to reference it: `...didTapModelWIthTypeAndNewText(type: ProfileTextfieldItem.ModelType...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this, here's what you should do:

```
struct ProfileTextfieldItem {

    var txtfPlaceholder: String
    var bottomTxt: String
    var modelType: ModelType

    enum ModelType {
        case phone
        case skype
    }
}
```

In Swift, `enum`s are Types, they can be used just like `class`es and `struct`s. To make an instance of this, do:

```
let tesEnum = ProfileTextfieldItem(txtfPlaceholder: "o.ivanova", bottomTxt: "Логин Skype", modelType: .phone)
```

Note the third parameter has a `.` in front of it and is called `modelType`, not `enumType`.

Comment: great answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should define the struct like this:

```
struct ProfileTextfieldItem {

    var txtfPlaceholder: String
    var bottomTxt: String
    var modelType : ModelType

    enum ModelType {
        case phone
        case skype
    }
}
```

and initial the var tesEnum like this:

```
let tesEnum = ProfileTextfieldItem(txtfPlaceholder: "o.ivanova", bottomTxt: "Логин Skype", modelType: .phone)
```

Comment: It looks like your answer is similar to @paper1111's answer.

Comment: @AnhPham it look like it copied